# Dotted focus line is not visible around images on a web page

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a dotted line around an image when the focus is on the image.
But this doesn't work as soon as I add `outline-style: dotted;`.
I could remove `style = "display:block"`, but then the dotted line is not displayed exactly around the image.
My code works fine in Mozilla Firefox, but it doesn't work in Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Opera and Safari.

What do I have to do so that the dotted line around an image is visible in all browsers?

And here's my code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type = "text/css">
      a:focus {
        outline-width: 2px;
        outline-style: dotted;
        outline-color: #ff0000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type = "text" tabindex = "10" style = "width:200px" value = "Click here and then press 'Tab'"><p>
    <a href = "" tabindex = "20">Link 1</a><p>
    <a href = "" tabindex = "30"><img src = "image.gif" style = "display:block"></a><p>
    <a href = "" tabindex = "40">Link 2</a><p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `inline-block` on the parent anchor and `block` on the image. This works for me in Edge/Chrome.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type = "text/css">
      a:focus {
        outline-width: 2px;
        outline-style: dotted;
        outline-color: #ff0000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type = "text" tabindex = "10" style = "width:200px" value = "Click here and then press 'Tab'"><p>
    <a href = "" tabindex = "20">Link 1</a><p>
    <a href = "" tabindex = "30" style = "display:inline-block"><img src = "image.gif" style = "display:block"></a><p>
    <a href = "" tabindex = "40">Link 2</a><p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this works in all browsers. Great, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Safari, the dotted line is not even displayed on text links because you can't use the 'Tab' key to set the focus to an anchor. 
But from what I've read, is this by design and can't be changed.
Is this really true?

Comment: I've never seen that before. All browsers should support focus out of the box for buttons and links with an `href`. Maybe try adding `tabindex="0"` to force it? It shouldn't change the tab order.

Comment: If I set the focus to the anchor (with a mouse click or with JavaScript), then it works in Safari, too. But in my Safari I can't set the focus to an anchor with the 'Tab' key. Are you really able to set the focus to 'Link 1' and 'Link 2' in your Safari with the 'Tab' key on the above code snippet?

Comment: I don't have a Mac device to test Safari on, but what you're describing is the expected behavior for `tabindex="-1"`. Specifically, you can focus the element by clicking or with JavaScript, but not with the keyboard. Have you tried `tabindex="0"` on the link?

Comment: I don't have a Mac device either. I just test it in Safari on my Windows laptop and there the anchors are not accessible with the 'Tab' key (also not with ```tabindex="0"```). What I've read, is this by design and can't be changed. I can't believe this, but I've no idea how to enable tab stops on anchors in Safari. I just know, in my Safari it doesn't work. But if someone with a Mac device can confirm that this is wrong and that also in Safari the anchors are accessible with the 'Tab' key, that would be great, because then it's just a problem on the Safari Windows edition.

Comment: @Seeky, take a look at https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2014/10/03/link-tabbing-firefox-osx.html. It looks like that's expected behavior in Safari and it can be changed in preferences.

Comment: I think I found a workaround for an anchor that also works in Safari with Safari's default browser settings (see answer and code snippet below).

Answer (score 0):

And here's a workaround that also works in Safari:

(Note: By default, you can't use the 'Tab' key to set the focus to an anchor in Safari)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type = "text/css">
      a:focus {
        outline-width: 2px;
        outline-style: dotted;
        outline-color: #ff0000;
      }
      div:focus {
        outline-width: 2px;
        outline-style: dotted;
        outline-color: #ff0000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type = "text" tabindex = "10" style = "width:200px" value = "Click here and then press 'Tab'"><p>
    <a href = "" tabindex = "20">This tab stop doesn't work in Safari</a><p>
    <div style = "color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; user-select:none; -khtml-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; display:inline-block" onclick = "window.location.href = ''" onkeypress = "if (event.keyCode == 13) {window.location.href = ''}" tabindex = "30">This tab stop also works with Safari</div><p>
    <div style = "cursor:pointer; display:inline-block" tabindex = "40"><img src = "image.gif" style = "display:block"></div><p>
    <div style = "color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; user-select:none; -khtml-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; display:inline-block" onclick = "window.location.href = ''" onkeypress = "if (event.keyCode == 13) {window.location.href = ''}" tabindex = "50">This tab stop also works with Safari</div><p>
  </body>
</html>
```